# OpenSSL problem with returned SHA256 value - C++

Tags: c++, openssl

I need help with generating SHA256 value with OpenSSL. I have code:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

int generateSHA256() {
    unsigned char temp[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char buf[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    const unsigned char *charToGenerate;
    size_t lenCharToGenerate;

    memset(buf, 0x0, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2);
    memset(temp, 0x0, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);

    SHA256(charToGenerate, lenCharToGenerate, temp);

    for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf_s((char *)&(buf[i * 2]), sizeof(buf) / 2, "%02x", temp[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And returned SHA256 value is not correct.

When this code is changed to return SHA1, then value is correct. Code is exactly the same:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

int generateSHA() {
    unsigned char temp[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char buf[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    const unsigned char *charToGenerate;
    size_t lenCharToGenerate;

    memset(buf, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2);
    memset(temp, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);

    SHA1(charToGenerate, lenCharToGenerate, temp);

    for (int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf_s((char *)&(buf[i * 2]), sizeof(buf) / 2, "%02x", temp[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Does anybody know what is missing, so that code would return correct SHA256 value?

I do not know why does it work for SHA1, but for SHA256 is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal of this is to produce an asci hex string of the sha bytes (in either case), your `sprintf_s` loop (a) is lying, the target buffer is decreasingly smaller as you march up so repeatedly passing `sizeof(buf)/2` is a lie, and (b) invokes undefined behavior on the final write, which will produce a three character output when you include a terminator, but by that time you're only two bytes away from end-of-buffer).

If you're going to do this in C++, then start using the standard library; it come in handy in oh-so-many ways. Also, use the EVP family (which all modern OpenSSL applications should use if they have any sense; it becomes so much easier in the long run).

```
// standard includes
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

// openssl libraries
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

namespace OpenSSL
{
    struct Delete
    {
        void operator()(EVP_MD_CTX *p) const
        {
            EVP_MD_CTX_free(p);
        }
    };

    template<class T>
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, Delete>;
}
using EVP_MD_CTX_ptr = OpenSSL::Ptr<EVP_MD_CTX>;

// generic MD digest runner 
std::string generateDigest(const void *src, size_t slen, const EVP_MD* digest)
{
    unsigned int mdlen = EVP_MD_size(digest);
    std::vector<uint8_t> md(mdlen);
    
    EVP_MD_CTX_ptr ctx(EVP_MD_CTX_new());
    EVP_DigestInit(ctx.get(), digest);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx.get(), src, slen);
    EVP_DigestFinal(ctx.get(), md.data(), &mdlen);

    // build output string
    static const char halpha[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(mdlen * 2);
    for (auto b : md)
    {
        result.push_back(halpha[(b >> 4) & 0xF]);
        result.push_back(halpha[b & 0xF]);
    }
    return result;
}

std::string generateSHA1(const void *src, std::size_t slen)
{
    return generateDigest(src, slen, EVP_sha1());
}

std::string generateSHA256(const void *src, std::size_t slen)
{
    return generateDigest(src, slen, EVP_sha256());
}

int main()
{
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    static const char msg[]     = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    static const char kat1[]    = "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12";
    static const char kat256[]  = "d7a8fbb307d7809469ca9abcb0082e4f8d5651e46d3cdb762d02d0bf37c9e592";

    auto s = generateSHA1(msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
    if (s != kat1)
    {
        std::cout << "SHA1 FAIL\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    s = generateSHA256(msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
    if (s != kat256)
    {
        std::cout << "SHA256 FAIL\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "Success!!\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
Success!!
```

Comment: My example is simplified. I need to return char type. Thank you on explanation and code, it will help me a lot. Cheers!